# Are real numbers only an approximation of a continuous line?

Tags: geometry, continuity

It is clear for me that the $\mathbb R$ set is infinite, but I cannot understand that it is continuous (I am an engineer with formal education in calculus, algebra, geometry, discrete maths and others but I am far from being a mathematician).

Based on the Dedekind's formulations, if I can devide a whole set in two parts from a single point, it must be continuous.

My idea is the following: if I take two points in a line defined in $\mathbb R$, I will have a gap that I can fill with another number. But now I would have two gaps between the three numbers. The set of $\mathbb R$ contains enough numbers to fill the gaps, but it includes the same number of gaps as well (?).

In general, I suppose no number defined by a finite number of symbols can be infinite. In the case of $1/3$, having $x = 0,3333...$, for the next digit $d$, I will have only options $2, 3, 4$, having $x<1/3$ for $d=2$; $x=1/3$, for $d=3$ and $x>1/3$, for $d=4$, but nothing in between (?).

My question is: is it really possible to express a line as a set of non-continous dots?

It is clear to me that $y=2x+1$ is a continuous line. But defining $x$ in $\mathbb R$ feels different to me.

This question can be a bit more philosophical than mathematical and the answer could be very simple. I just cannot avoid this question anymore. I apologize with the community for such a question with so little formality. I am just a curious person who enjoys learning everyday a bit more.

Comment: I read that post. But I think it does not answer my question. As I said, for me it is totally clear that R is infinite and that it is complete. But about continuity, it still feels like a bunch of dots and not like a soft line.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> It sounds as if you might be trying to get at _connectedness_ of the real line...? If so, that's not a property of the real numbers alone, but also depends on the concepts of _open intervals_ and "nearness." (If it matters, in mathematics, "continuous" is a property of functions related to the concept of limits in the sense of calculus.)

Comment: if you are serious about this, you might enjoy intuitionistic mathematics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionism  My impression is that this has been popular with computer science professors, and lots of varieties exist now.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually came across the topic by reading this article https://www.quantamagazine.org/does-time-really-flow-new-clues-come-from-a-century-old-approach-to-math-20200407/ and thinking about set theory and the Gödel's incompleteness ideas.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I am not sure if correctly understood what you wrote in parens. I remember from calculus the definition of a function be continuous if every $x$ in the has a corresponding $f(x)$. I have the idea, I can define precisely $\pi$ as a fraction, but every value I could calculate for $\pi$ would be an approximation. Or am I wrong thinking this way? Thank you in advance. I just would like to know your opinion from geometry.

Comment: Relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44102/is-the-analysis-as-taught-in-universities-in-fact-the-analysis-of-definable-numb

Comment: Thank you! I found this article very useful as well: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_continuum

Comment: You may like infinitesimals and the hyperreal line: they "pack more numbers" in a line. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal

Comment: The parenthetical remark was about the use of "continuity" in this context, though I probably mis-guessed the intent of the question. :) <> My views on how mathematics connects to the physical universe are rather far from my formal training. This comment is too small to contain details, but in my view time and space seem to be neither infinite nor infinitesimal. Numbers (reals, rationals, ...) are a useful approximations of distance and duration at human scales. At extremely large (cosmological) and small (Planck) scales, however, numerical descriptions appear to break down fundamentally.